# Button inside label triggers (sometimes double trigger \ double click)

Tags: html, button, input, label

There was similar question, but i don't have enough reputation to post an answer, so i'm doing it as "new question"

the problem is:

```html
<label>
  <button type="button">something 1</button>
  <button type="button">something 2</button>
  <input>
</label>
```

If you will click on anywhere inside the label - it will trigger first button, not second button, not focus into input

thats because `label` triggers whatever it finds first inside it

so if you'll click on `something 2` button - you will have 2 clicks: label will trigger first button and you (as user) will trigger second button

and it is actually easy solvable

```html
<label for="unique">
  <button type="button">something 1</button>
  <button type="button">something 2</button>
  <input id="unique">
</label>
```

that way label will always know what exactly to trigger

Comment: If you already found an answer to your question, please post it as an answer and not as part of the question.
That being said, general advice is [“Don't place interactive elements such as anchors or buttons inside a label.“](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#interactive_content)

Comment: Also, I just saw that it’s not allowed per [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element) to place _labelable elements_ (that includes buttons) inside a label.

Comment: Regarding your first point: unfortunately i don't have enought reputation (as i stated in the question) to post that as comment.;;;

The question itself was marked as closed, so also could not post as answer.;;;


Regarding "standards" point - unfortunately standard does not always work. For example it is also not supposed to put "interactable" elements inside each other, yet google drive does it (buttons inside list items, which are also buttons i think).;;;

in our case it is also fairly tricky situation, where we had to find a workaround for the problem, and i wanted to share it.

Comment: Nobody forces you to put these buttons inside the label element, and as stated it can be harmful. You can create a container around the label and bind any event handlers on that one. The idea of the standard is that you should not put _natively interactive elements_ inside each other. A list item (G Drive) is not natively interactive. The key is that you can control interactivity by binding your own event handlers. So wouldn’t the underlying question be how to implement interactivity on a parent AND a child element?

Comment: So if you are interested, we could try to find a solution to that question which is less confusing to users and avoids the pitfalls of having several interactive elements inside a label. If you are, add your final goal to the question.

Comment: 1) thanks for the answer! i think thats exactly what i was looking for. (2) i was talking about previous gdrive version, they had something like `<a> <button/> <button> <button/> </button> </a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General advise is [“Don't place interactive elements such as anchors or buttons inside a label.“](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#interactive_content)

While using the `for` attribute might work around the part of the problem with clicking the label, it poses other issues.

```
// don’t put buttons in labels!
<label for="unique">
  <button type="button">something 1</button>
  <button type="button">something 2</button>
  <input id="unique">
</label>
```

The [HTML Standard does not allow additional interactive elements in a `<label>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element) to begin with:

> Content model:
> Phrasing content, but with no descendant labelable elements unless it is the element's labeled control, and no descendant label elements.

So this might work today, but since it’s not supported by the standard, browser vendors are free to change behaviour.

> The  HTML element represents a caption for an item in a user interface.

The main [purpose of a label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) is to provide an accessible text to an input, so that users know what to enter, even when using assistive technology like screen readers or voice control. The label’s text contents will therefore be used to label the input, taking into account all included texts. It will be captioned “something 1 something 2”.

This is not very good, so my advise would be to not rely on the `for` attribute to fix the click issue, but to separate it and implement the click behaviour yourself.

Using a `<fieldset>` will have the advantage of the controls being grouped for assistive technology as well, so entering or leaving the group with the focus will be announced.

```js
focusInput = e => e.currentTarget.querySelector('input').focus();
action = e => {
  alert('Action!');
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<fieldset onclick="focusInput(event)">
  <legend>Group Title</legend>
  <button type="button" onclick="action(event)">something 1</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="action(event)">something 2</button>
  <br>
  <label>
    Input Label
    <input>
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Note that no keyboard handlers are bound to the fieldset, as this would once again be confusing to keyboard users.